# How to find the offset of a message in Kafka Topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

How to find the offset of a message in Kafka Topic? Does the offset contains multiple messages or a single message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offsets only link to a single message within a single partition of a topic.

You could have the same offset be available in many partitions and many topics, but there is almost no correlation between those values unless you explictly made the producers do that.

There is no easy way to find the offset for a single message. You need to scan the whole topic (or at least a single partition)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've read the message using a `consume()` or `poll()`, and you're interested in the details of this message, you can find the corresponding partition and offset using the following code:

```
# assuming you have a Kafka consumer in place
msg = consumer.consume()
partition = msg.partition()
offset = msg.offset()
```

A Kafka topic is divided into partitions. Kafka distributes the incoming messages in a round robin fashion across partitions (unless you've specified some key on which to partition). So, for a random message that you haven't read, you may have to scan all partitions to find the message, and then the corresponding offset.

Comment: I am getting `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'partition'`. Using kafka-python

Comment: Also, there is no `consume()` on the `KafkaConsumer`, only `poll`.